# PL/SQL: Хеширование длинного числа по группам

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Вопрос заключается в следующем:

Как известно, у базы данных Oracle, тип NUMBER имеет ограничение в длине значения (если не ошибаюсь, то 38). У меня имеется функция, которая достает число из таблицы, хеширует его, после чего помещает обратно в таблицу, заменяя исходное число. Однако, из-за вышеуказанного ограничения, я столкнулся с проблемой корректного хеширования. Обязательно я должен получить на выходе число.

Были мысли хешировать по группам (например, с 1 по 38 - 1я группа, с 39 и ... т.д. - 2я группа, а после, "склеить" группы чисел), сделав, например, функцию-обертку, но я новичок в изучении pl/sql, поэтому, хотел бы спросить у более грамотных людей, как можно реализовать данную идею?

Думаю, кто-нибудь да сталкивался с данной проблемой, и ответы будут полезны многим.

Заранее всем благодарен!

**UPD:**

Основная функция хеширования числа:

```
function hash_number_by_key(p_in varchar2, hash_length number, p_k varchar2) return number is
    hash number (38);
    result number (38);
    begin
        if (p_in is not null) then
            hash := hash_utils.hash_to_number(dbms_crypto.mac(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_in),
                                                dbms_crypto.HMAC_SH1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_k)));

            if hash_length = 0 or hash_length is null then
                result := to_number(rpad(hash, length(p_in), hash));
            else
                if hash_length <= 38 and hash_length >= 1 then
                    result := to_number(rpad(hash, hash_length, hash));
                else
                    raise_application_error(-20021,
                    'Incorrect length. Length must be from 1 to 38. Hash length: '||hash_length);
                end if;
            end if;
        else
            result := null;
        end if;

        return result;
    end hash_number_by_key;
```

Функция, где она используется:

```
function hash_phone_by_key(p_in varchar2, p_k varchar2) return varchar2 is
    idx int;
    pos int;
    lngth int;
    buffer varchar2 (4000);
    pattern varchar2 (4000);
    numbers varchar(4000);
    hash varchar2 (4000);
    result varchar2 (4000);
    begin
        if p_in is not null then

            buffer := REGEXP_REPLACE(p_in, '[[:alpha:]]', '');

            lngth := LENGTH(numbers);
            if lngth > 0 then
              hash := hash_number_by_key(numbers, lngth, p_k);
              idx := 1;
              for pos in 1..LENGTH(pattern)
              loop
                if '0' = substr(pattern, pos, 1) then
                  result := result || substr(hash, idx, 1);
                  idx := idx + 1;
                else
                  result := result || substr(pattern, pos, 1);
                end if;
              end loop;
            end if;

            return result;
        else
            return null;
        end if;
    end hash_phone_by_key;
```

Comment: А вам действительно нужен такой длинный хеш? И действительно только из цифр? Если да, возможно просто положить ваш хэш как строку?

Comment: @Viktorov Нужен, да. Есть уже изначально реализованные функции в пакетах, которые работают только с числами. Поэтому приходится подстраиваться под них.

Вот все же с циклом идея не дает мне покоя.

Comment: Тогда я не понял, что значит хэшировать по группам. Вы имеете ввиду, разбить хэш на группы и положить эти группы в разные колонки?

Comment: Не совсем:
Разбить исходное число на группы, хэшировать по частям, и после "склеить" их, после чего поместить его в колонку, откуда было взято исходное число

Comment: А почему вы решили, что так хэш станет корочек?

Comment: Что у вас вообще за функция?

Comment: @Viktorov добавил в вопрос мой pl/sql код, который имеется. Да, пожалуй, с этого и стоило начинать; извините.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы так просто хэшируете телефоны?

Comment: На данном примере - да.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит подумать о хранении просто хэша как строки без приведения к числу. Ради чего нужно приводить обязательно хэш к числу?

Comment: Если быть более точным, то в столбец имеет тип varchar2 (как вариант), из него берутся только числа, которые там находятся (уже средствами другого языка). Если мне не изменяет память, то это используется для того, чтобы пользователь мог работать с любыми типами значений (будь это number или varchar). Без учета "тире" и "слэшей", длинна числа равна 40 (на рисунке):

[Пример](https://sun1-10.userapi.com/c831508/v831508242/174bf7/Tb6EW-1-Epc.jpg).

Я пока затрудняюсь ответить, ради чего нужно приведение хэша к числу.

Comment: Теперь я совсем запутался. А чего вы в результате то хотите?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81639/discussion-between-alex-and-viktorov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить данную проблему, написав функцию-обертку, которая обрезает длинное число по 38 символов, хэширует, и склеивает с предыдущим значением. Вот код данной функции, который мне помог (выкладываю, может кому-то пригодится):

```
function hash_to_long_number(p_in number) return varchar2 is
    p_in_copy varchar2(4000) := p_in;
    buffer varchar2(4000);
    result varchar2(4000);

    accuracy number := 38;

    begin
        while length(p_in_copy) >= 0
        loop
        if (length(p_in_copy) > accuracy) then
            buffer := substr(p_in_copy, 1, accuracy);
            p_in_copy := substr(p_in_copy, length(buffer) + 1, length(p_in_copy));
        else
            buffer := p_in_copy;
            p_in_copy := substr(p_in_copy, length(buffer) + 1, length(p_in_copy));
        end if;

        buffer := hash_number(buffer, length(buffer));
        result := result || buffer;
        end loop;
    return result;
end hash_to_long_number_by_key;
```